# How do I make a UITableViewCell resize when a UITextView size changes?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, snapkit

I'm having an Auto Layout with SnapKit issue. I added a UITextView to a UITableViewCell, and I want the cell to expand as the text view expands when the user adds content. However, in reality, when the the text view attempts to expand, the cell constraints break. Here is my code:

**TextFieldTableViewCell:**

```
import UIKit

class TextFieldTableViewCell: FieldTableViewCell {

  let textView = EditableTextView()

  override func setUpViews() {
    super.setUpViews()

    setUpTextView()
  }

  private func setUpTextView() {
    contentView.addSubview(textView)

    textView.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 10000), for: .vertical)
    textView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 10000), for: .vertical)

    textView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
      make.top.equalTo(fieldLabel.snp.bottom).offset(margin)
      make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(margin)
      make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-margin)
      make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-margin)
    }
  }

}
```

**EditableTextView:**

```
import UIKit

class EditableTextView: UITextView {

  override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()

    isEditable = true
    isScrollEnabled = false
  }

}
```

And here is my error:

```
2019-06-20 18:23:10.276724-0500 Campaign Detective[1127:169808] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-06-20 18:23:10.278517-0500 Campaign Detective[1127:169808] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2019-06-20 18:23:13.479469-0500 Campaign Detective[1127:169808] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x2831c90e0 Campaign_Detective.EditableTextView:0x140813200'Yeah I\U2019ll call them later...'.height == 86 Hug:10000 CompressionResistance:10000   (active)>",
    "<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x2831f82a0@FieldTableViewCell.swift#37 UILabel:0x13fb03540.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x13fb03830.top + 15.0>",
    "<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x2831d1740@TextFieldTableViewCell.swift#20 Campaign_Detective.EditableTextView:0x140813200.top == UILabel:0x13fb03540.bottom + 15.0>",
    "<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x2831d1920@TextFieldTableViewCell.swift#23 Campaign_Detective.EditableTextView:0x140813200.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x13fb03830.bottom - 15.0>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2836b5040 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x13fb03830.height == 123.333   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x2831c90e0 Campaign_Detective.EditableTextView:0x140813200'Yeah I'll call them later...'.height == 86 Hug:10000 CompressionResistance:10000   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

The cell never resizes, because the `UITableViewCellContentView:0x13fb03830.height` constraint isn't changed. Shouldn't this be changed by the system to the new calculated height? When I set `.priority(.high)` to every constraint, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The following line tells the engine that you prefer textView to shrink when there's not enough space. Probably that's not what you want

```
textView.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 10000), for: .vertical)
```

If your set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension`, after the user finished editing you can just call

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

and this should recalculate the cell's height and update it

Answer (score 1):

Table views and cells do not auto-size without a little help.

Change your cell class like this:

```
// add the UITextViewDelegate
class TextFieldTableViewCell: FieldTableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    let textView = EditableTextView()

    // this will allow the cell to "call back" to the controller when the text is edited
    var callback: ((String) -> ())?

    // when the text changes, tell the controller to update the dataSource and the table layout
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        callback?(textView.text!)
    }

    override func setUpViews() {
        super.setUpViews()

        setUpTextView()
    }

    private func setUpTextView() {
        contentView.addSubview(textView)

        // set the delegate so textViewDidChange will be triggered on editing
        textView.delegate = self

        // use default Hugging and Compression
        //textView.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 10000), for: .vertical)
        //textView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 10000), for: .vertical)

        textView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(fieldLabel.snp.bottom).offset(margin)
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(margin)
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview().offset(-margin)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-margin)
        }
    }

}
```

Then, in your controller class, change `cellForRowAt` as follows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextFieldTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TextFieldTableViewCell

    // assuming you have an array of strings for the text views
    cell.textView.text = theData[indexPath.row]

    // when the text in the cell is edited, the cell will "call back"
    // and we can update the data source and tell the tableView to
    // update its layout
    cell.callback = { (str) in
        self.theData[indexPath.row] = str
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    return cell

}
```