# Dynamic height for UITextView with multiple line(NSString) inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

There are 3 cells in my tableview. In the last cell am loading UITextView.

UITextView's text is NSString which has some strings with new line. This is how I want to display the strings in UITextView. I have to show my data like bullet points(one by one) in the text view.

Apple,

Banana,

Orange

Now the problem is height of the cell. UITableViewAutomaticDimension not expanding the cell which has UITextView

Below is my code in heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 55;
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
 } else {
    return 55;
 }
```

If I try to calculate the height for cell which is having UITextView, it is not considering the new lines in NSString.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hope this will help -> https://www.swiftdevcenter.com/the-dynamic-height-of-uitextview-inside-uitableviewcell-swift/

Comment: If you disable scrolling on your `UITextView` you shouldn't have to do anything other than set constraints (just like you would on a multi-line `UILabel`). No need for `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. Note: if your text view is editable, you'll need to call back to tell the table view controller to update the table, just as you would when dynamically changing the text in a multi-line label.

Comment: It's not working for me. I have disabled the scroll, there is no edit for the textview.  It's just to show the text. I have two textviews horizontally, first textView width is 100, height > 50 and the remaining space is for next (multi line) textview with constraints trailing(to the superview) & leading(to the first textview) 10, height > 50.

Comment: @Sivagami - our question description says *"There are 3 cells in my tableview..."* but then your code shows `if (indexPath.row == 3) ...`? Table view rows are Zero-based, so with three rows you `indexPath.row` will be either 0, 1 or 2. Is that the problem?

Comment: @DonMag Sorry mistakenly typed 3 while asking question, Nope its not the problem, In code, indexPath.row is 2 only. Have edited my question.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sivagami - take a look at this... works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56704910/6257435